# Scala nested types with traits

Tags: scala

I've got something like this:

```
trait ObjectId {
  val value: Long
}
case class Room(id: Option[Room.Id])

case object Room {
  case class Id(value: Long) extends ObjectId   
}

case class Tree(id: Option[Tree.Id])

case object Tree {
  case class Id(value: Long) extends ObjectId  
}
```

What I want to do is create class `FromDB` with field id, of type which extends trait `ObjectId` and is nested inside `T`:

```
case class FromDB[T](value: T, id)
```

for example it should work as follows:

```
FromDB[Room](Room, Room.Id)
FromDB[Tree](Tree, Tree.Id)
```

Comment: `case class FromDB[T <: Id]` should do the trick. It will require type `T` that extends `Id`

Comment: yeah, but T is not extending Id, case class Id inside object T extends trait Id

Comment: Alright, I could use more classes then; what is `Tree`? What is `domain.Id`? Also, the code that you provided is missing an opening brace.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use depenent types and let type inference work for you:

```
trait ObjectId {
    val value: Long
}

trait Model[T] {
    type Id <: ObjectId
}

case class Room(id: Option[Room.Id])

object Room extends Model[Room] {
    case class Id(value: Long) extends ObjectId
}

case class Tree(id: Option[Tree.Id])

object Tree extends Model[Tree] {
    case class Id(value: Long) extends ObjectId
}

case class FromDB[T, I <: Model[T]](value: T, id: I#Id)

val room = Room(Some(Room.Id(1)))

FromDB(room, room.id.get) // compiles
FromDB(room, Tree.Id(123)) // doesn't compile
```

Here, `Model[T]` defines a type `Id` which is constrained to be a child of `ObjectId`. Each instance of `Model[T]` has its own implementation of `Id`.

In `FromDB[T, I <: Model[T]]`, the compiler will infere `I` if `id` is an instance of the correct `Model[T]`, it won't compile otherwise.